# Python: How to get URL when running a HTTP proxy server?

Tags: python, http, sockets, proxy

I am creating an HTTP Proxy Server that is able to retrieve the URL of the website requested by a user. I am only allowed to use a **single file** for my HTTP Proxy Server (I can't have multiple files).

I am able within a infinite running while loop to detect a connection and the address and receive a message from the client:

```
while True:
    conn, addr = created_socket.accept()
    data_received = conn.recv(1024)
    print(data_received)
```

When I run my server on a specified port and type the [IP Address]:[Port Number] into Chrome, I get the following result after printing data_received:

`b'GET /www.google.com HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.2:5050\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n\r\n`

Is there a systematic way in which I can retrieve the URL (in this case, `www.google.com`)? Right now, I am coding in a constant buffer size for `conn.recv` (`1024`). However, I was wondering if there was first a way to first retrieve the message size of the client, store it in a variable, and then pass that variable to the buffer size parameter for `recv`?

Comment: No. The HTTP protocol is what it is. You have to parse the first line you receive for the URL. You also have to implement the CONNECT method.

Comment: @user207421 Understood. What, if anything should I do if the message received by the connection exceeds the hard-coded buffer size?

Comment: You don't want the whole message. You only want the first line. Then you open the upstream connection to the indicated target, write that line to it, then start copying data in both directions.